# Get parent record two levels up

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

Suppose I have this data structure in my db.

**Parent_table**

```
ParentID
someOtherProp
```

having 1:N relation with `Child_table` as shown below

```
 ChildID
 ParentID
```

This `Child_table` further has a child table with 1:N relationship as     `SubChild_table`

```
SubChildID
ChildID
```

Now, I have `SubChildID`. How can I get access to Parent_table's `someOtherProp`? I tried with `.Include()`, but I am really not sure how to write. So far I have something like this:

```
var foo = _db.Parent_table
  .Include(c => c.Child_table
    .Select(d => d.SubChild_table
    .Where(f => f.SubChildID == subChildID)))
    .Select(r => r.someOtherProp)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

The error I get is:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.  Parameter name: path

Comment: Could you not use JOINS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you have the foreign key relationships set

```
var foo = _db.SubChild_tables.Where(sc => sc.SubChildId == id).Single().Child_table.Parent_Table.SomeOtherProp;
```

Comment: This will work **if** (in addition to the foreign key relationships you mention) the `id` provided is a valid SubChildId, and if every SubChild has a Child, and every Child has a Parent.

Comment: Altought all of the answers are alike, I'll accept yours, because of the time. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `.Include` unless you want to *return* the included properties. You're free to access all properties of all objects in the hierarchy while constructing the query.

So, I think what you want is:

```
var foo = (from p in _db.Parent_table
          join c in _db.Child_table on p.ParentId equals c.ParentId
          join s in _db.SubChild_table on c.ChildId equals s.ChildId
          where s.SubChildId == subChildId
          select p.someOtherProp).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess ..

```
var foo = from pt in Parent_table
            join ct in Child_table
              on pt.ParentID equals ct.ParentID
            join sct in SubChild_table
              on ct.ChildID equals sct.ChildID
            where sct.SubChildID == "YourValue"
            select new {
                pt.SomeOtherProp
            };
```

Or

```
var foo = Parent_table
    .Join(Child_table, p => p.ParentID, c => c.ParentID, (p, c) => new { p, c })
    .Join(SubChild_table, sc => sc.c.ChildID, c => c.ChildID, (sc, c) => new { sc, c })
    .Where(sc.SubCHildID == "YourValue")
    .Select(m => new { 
        m.p.someOtherProp
    });
```